# is my analytical solution for Heat Equation correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, analyticity

Could you please check my analytical solution for accuracy and correctness?

Consider the heat equation: $$ u_t(x, t)=u_{x x}(x, t) $$
where $$ 0<x<1, \quad t>0 $$ Neumann Boundary condition:
$$ \begin{gathered} 
u_x(0, t)=u, \quad t>0 \\ u_x(1, t)=-u, \quad t>0 
\end{gathered} $$
Initial condition: $$ u(x, 0)=1, \quad 0<x<1 $$

To solve the heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions using the method of separation of variables, we assume that the solution can be expressed as a product of functions of $x$ and $t$
$$
u(x, t)=X(x) T(t)
$$
Substituting this into the heat equation, we get
$$
X T^{\prime}=X^n T
$$
Dividing both sides by XT, we obtain:
$$
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}=\frac{X^n}{X}=-\lambda
$$
where $\lambda$ is the separation constant. Thus, we have two ODEs to solve:
$$
T^{\prime}+\lambda T=0 \text { and } X^{\prime \prime}+\lambda X=0
$$
The Neumann boundary conditions can be expressed in terms of the solution of $X(x)$, follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& X^{\prime}(0)=u=k_1 \\
& X^{\prime}(1)=-u=-k_2
\end{aligned}
$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants.
Solving the ODE for $T(t)$, we get
$$
T(t)=c_1 e^{-\lambda t}
$$
where $c_1$ is a constant.
Solving the $O D E$ for $X(x)$, we get
$$
X(x)=c_2 \cos (\sqrt{\lambda} x)+c_3 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda} x)
$$
Using the boundary conditions for $X(x)$. we get.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& X^{\prime}(0)=-c_2 \sqrt{\lambda}=u \\
& X^{\prime}(1)=-c_2 \sqrt{\lambda} \sin (\sqrt{\lambda})+c_2 \sqrt{\lambda} \cos (\sqrt{\lambda})=-u
\end{aligned}
$$
Solving for $c_2$ and $c_3$, we get
$$
c_2=-\frac{u}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \text { and } c_3=\frac{u}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \sin (\sqrt{\lambda})
$$
Substituting the expressions for $T(t)$ and $X(x)$ into the solution for $u(x, t)$, we get
$$
u(x, t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n} x\right) e^{-\lambda_n t}
$$
where $\lambda_n = n^2\pi^2$ and $b_n$ is given by:$$
b_n=\frac{2}{u \sqrt{\lambda_n} \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\right)} \int_0^1 u(x, 0) \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n} x\right) d x
$$
Using the initial condition, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_n & =\frac{2}{u \sqrt{\lambda_n} \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\right)} \int_0^1 \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n} x\right) d x \\
& =\frac{2}{u \sqrt{\lambda_n} \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\right)}\left[\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda_n} x\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\right]_0^1 \\
& =\frac{2}{u \pi n}(-1)^{n+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, the analytic solution for the heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions and initial condition is:

$$
u(x, t)=\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cos (n \pi x) e^{-n^2 n^2 t}
$$
where $\lambda_n = n^2\pi^2$ is the separation constant, and $n$ is a positive integer. The solution is obtained using the method of separation of variables, where we assume that the solution can be expressed as a product of two functions of x and t: $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$. We then solve the resulting ODEs for $X(x)$ and $T(t)$, subject to the given Neumann boundary conditions and initial condition. The solution involves an infinite series of terms, each representing a different mode of heat transfer. The constant $\lambda_n$ is the eigenvalue associated with the $n$th mode, and determines the rate of decay of the corresponding mode as time progresses.